# Is it standard for Jest to exit with a status 1 if any test fails?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

When a test fails within Jest it always exits throwing an npm error "errno 1". I find this is be rather ugly and makes it seem rather alarming. Is this standard for Jest?  I would much prefer to just see the first 5 lines.

```
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 failed, 3 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        41.881s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! applitoolsci@1.0.0 test: `jest`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the applitoolsci@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/nicklee/.npm/_logs/2019-04-30T19_33_00_584Z-debug.log
```

Comment: It is pretty much universal behaviour for _any_ process to exit with a non-zero exit code if things went wrong. Whether you think it's ugly should be irrelevant, given that the solution is to fix your tests so that they pass, and jest doesn't error out. Dig through the jest runtime flags to see if you can make it "pretend to succeed anyway" on errors, but you shouldn't need to: error output is not meant to look nice, it's meant to show you things went wrong, so you can fix them and make the output look nice again.

Comment: No, `npm` doesn't usually exit with a status 1 and create a debug log when a test fails.  What is `applitoolsci@1.0.0`?  How are you launching `Jest`?

Comment: This behavior is exactly how it should be to abort a GitHub deploy action on test fail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, it's not an issue, jest exits with status code 1 when the test case failed.We get that error when the any test or spec file fails then it exits with status 1(`Exit status 1`) and when it successfully passed the all test cases then it exits with 0.
That is usual behavior of node based `CLI` tools.Check this [closed issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7803) too

But you can use `jest-html reporter` or [`jest-stare`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-stare) package to find which suite failed while running as a workaround.